# How to convert System.Byte[] to bitmap?

Tags: android, web-services, bitmap, imageview, android-ksoap2

I'm doing a job for the school but I'm having problems with the images.
I get System.Byte [] from my web service and I've tried several solutions and I can't convert to bitmap and add my ImageView. In my database the column "Image" appears .
Can someone help me? thanks

Here is my android code.

```
private String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private String URL = "http://X.X.X.X/ProjetoFinal/WSGestao.asmx?WSDL";
private String METHOD_NAME = "List_Images";
private String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/List_Images";
private String[] List;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_layout);

    new MyAsyncTask().execute();

}

private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String[]> {

    protected String[] doInBackground(Void... strings) {

        //connection to the web service
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

            //Fetch the server's response and add the list
            List = new String[response.getPropertyCount()];

            for (int i = 0; i < response.getPropertyCount(); i++) {

                List[i] = response.getProperty(i).toString();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return List;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);


        //convert to Bitmap

    }
}
```

The web service sends:

```
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<string>System.Byte[]</string>
<string>System.Byte[]</string>
<string>System.Byte[]</string>
<string>System.Byte[]</string>
<string>System.Byte[]</string>
<string>System.Byte[]</string>
<string>System.Byte[]</string>
<string>System.Byte[]</string>
</ArrayOfString>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public static void setImageViewWithByteArray(ImageView view, Byte[] data) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

Use this code to display byte [] on imageView

Comment: Hi. I tried to use this method but the null bitmap. I just passed my first object on the list and my imageview                                                                                                                             `setImageViewWithByteArray(img,result[0].getBytes());`

Comment: Log result [0] .getBytes () in the log and make sure that the result is correct.

Comment: The method receives:  [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13MwyDNanlCqBcq14CjhC8xJ_xc_0cGuN/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Your web service send you strings. And you trying to convert `System.Byte[]` string to image. But it is string, not image. Thats why it doesn't work.

`result[0].getBytes()` shows you this:

[image]

Here in `data` array there are 13 elements (length of `"System.Byte[]"` string is also 13). Each byte here is just `utf8` code of symbol in `"System.Byte[]"` string. 
83 is big `S` symbol, 121 is `y`, 115 is `s`  etc.

So you need to provide correct byte array of real image and use `setImageViewWithByteArray` method from `Destroyer` answer.